# Advice Needed: Deploying application to IIS - Can this be fully automated?

Tags: iis, automation

I am seeking advice: Ideally, I would like to give an Administrator (of the web server) one file (.exe, .msi, .bat, whatever you suggest), so that when they execute the package, it will setup my application (contains .aspx, .xap silverlight, web service .svc, etc.) on IIS.  This will include and certainly not be limited to such things in the IIS Manager, like creating a virtual directory, path, default document, security, and all of the IIS settings one finds via inetmgr and properties.  I would also maybe like to run a .bat file (not sure if this correct), but to check for certain settings and pinging other servers for status.

Many years ago, I used to automate everything and used concepts like .bat files - got the job done and it was amazing what I could do.  Fast forward a couple of years now and am approaching the automation process again.  I wanted to know if there is anything new out there.

Any and all advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite a bit of a learning curve but yes,  WiX / InstallShield / MSI can do this.   I've done installers for n-Tier / SOA systems including single tenant SaaS where you could run the application layer installer dozens of times creating new instances running on different host headers or ports pointed to different data layers and different configuration settings.  You could then do the same for the WebUI pointing to which ever application layer you want.

Basically whether it's instaling .NET,  setting up vDir / AppPools / WebSites / Extensions,  reading and writing XML config files,  executing SQL scripts, creating services  and so on it can all be done... if you take the time to learn it all.  Deployment Engineering is a bigger domain then it first appears to be.

As for .BAT, that's bad form.  First you work to leverage native capabilities before writing custom actions.   Then when you do have to write one, you design it to be declarative and transactional ( install, uninstall, rollback, commit ). WiX has a really nice framework called DTF that allows you to encapsulate  C# classes as if they were C++ from MSI's perspective and provides a nice interop library needed to talk to MSI during the install.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has a Web Setup Package project you can use for this.

Comment: Isn't that very limited?  How do you set up Security via this route?  Run other commands?

Comment: I haven't looked in details, but I assume you can do custom commands. Alternatively, you can use WiX to built an MSI.